# Rails 6: link to destroy_user_session_path using GET instead of DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, rails-ujs

I have just started a simple Rails 6.0.3.1 project.

I'm setting up the Devise actions, but the logout link doesn't seem to work. It's performing a `GET` request instead of a `DELETE` despite the fact that I specify the method:

```
- if user_signed_in?
  = link_to 'Logout',
    destroy_user_session_path,
    class: 'button is-light',
    method: :delete
```

Clicking the link yields:

[image: Rails error message showing the GET request]

There are no errors in the console:

[image: no console errors on click]

My `app/javascript/packs/application.js` looks like this:

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

So Rails ujs should be intercepting the link click and performing a `DELETE`, but it's not.

My `config/webpack/environment.js` looks like this:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const vue = require('./loaders/vue')

environment.plugins.prepend('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin())
environment.loaders.prepend('vue', vue)
module.exports = environment
```

I tried searching for a solution on other SO threads but I didn't find something that works. Some people suggested using a button instead of a link, but I want a link not a button.

The issue occurred after I installed Bulma CSS framework via yarn:

```sh
yarn add bulma
```

which I then imported into my project in `app/javascript/packs/application.scss` with:

```
@import '~bulma';
```

My layout file (`application.html.erb`) includes the lines:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

I've created a [simple dummy app](https://github.com/DaniG2k/myproject) to reproduce the problem.

Any advice on what I might be doing incorrectly here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see any JS error when you reload the page in browser's console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, I just checked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately found the solution.

I created the file `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss` where I put the line:

```
@import '~bulma';
```

Then, in `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.js` I added the line:

```js
import 'stylesheets/application'
```

It seems that webpacker requires the application.js file to import the appropriate CSS files in order to work.

Answer (score -1):

Can you add your html source in the question?

Also, you can try this instead:

```
- if user_signed_in?
  = link_to 'Logout',
    destroy_user_session_path,
    class: 'button is-light',
    data: {method: :delete}
```

notice the part: `data: {method: :delete}`

Comment: Changing to `data: {method: :delete}` makes no difference, a `GET` request still gets triggered.

The HTML that gets generated is: 

`<a class="button is-light" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Logout</a>`